# my script makes my whole bar to display none

Tags: javascript

I have a subscription box and im trying to make a X close button that remembers to not display next time with web storage or cookies. when i click the close button my whole side bar is set to display none. In stead of just id="gfxhsub" .

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById('mailclose').onclick = function(){
this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
return false;
};
};
</script>
```

html

```
<div id="gfxhsub" style="margin: 2em 0.5em; height: auto;">
<span id='mailclose'><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
[newsletter_signup_form id=6]
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the following code in your click event handler.

```
// 1st line: Select the div you want to hide.
// 2nd line: Set the style of the element to display: none;
var elem = document.querySelector('#gfxhsub');
elem.style.display = 'none';
```

Here's a working example.

```css
#mailclose {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('mailclose').onclick = function() {
      var elem = document.querySelector('#gfxhsub');
      elem.style.display = 'none';
      return false;
    };
  };
</script>
html

<div id="gfxhsub" style="margin: 2em 0.5em; height: auto;">
  <span id='mailclose'><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span> [newsletter_signup_form id=6]
</div>
```